# can indexing SQL tables improve the performance of a tableau dashboard?

Tags: sql, indexing, tableau-desktop

I have a very high level question.
could indexes on a sql server table improve the loading performance of a tableau dashboard?

if so - is there any best practice / guideline we could follow?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will speed up Tableau.  Just like the indexes speed up any query (if applied properly), Tableau is the same way - it's just querying the data and displaying the results.

Best practice ? Like everything else, analyse the usage to see where it is appropriate to apply indexes.  Not enough is bad, too many is bad.

Answer (score 1):

An index will speed up the extraction of the data to Tableaus database structure, but it will not speed up Tableau as you interact with it.  There is a Tableau community website where you can find best practices, etc. on.